# Is it possible to omit rounding of intermediate results during arithmetic operation on multiple FP operands?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, precision, cpu-architecture

Is there the possibility to do an arithmetic operation on multiple floating point operands without rounding intermediate results and just round the final result, and are there any architectures currently doing it? because as far as I've seen after two floating point operands are used in an addition/subtraction operation the result gets rounded before being used as an operand for another operation, also I've seen [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6567600).

**EDIT:**

Below are some examples considering single-precision format to elucidate the concept, 3 least significant bits of intermediate 27-bit mantissas taking part in arithmetic operation are guard, round and sticky bits; from examples You can see, using the intermediate mantissa bit structure utilized in a IEEE754 compliant FP system, avoiding rounding of intermediate values is possible and when it's done it'll achieve a more accurate result:

##### 1_Example 1

```
A-B = 101001000010001110110100 1 0 1×2^EXP

C   = 100011001011001010010100×2^(EXP-4) --> 
C   = 000010001100101100101001 0 1 0×2^EXP
```

1_1_If A-B-C is calculated after A-B is rounded:

```
Rounded A-B   = 101001000010001110110101×2^EXP
        A-B-C = 100110110101100010001011 1 1 0×2^EXP
Rounded A-B-C = 100110110101100010001100×2^EXP
```

1_2_If A-B-C is calculated without A-B being rounded:

```
        A-B-C = 100110110101100010001011 0 1 1×2^EXP
Rounded A-B-C = 100110110101100010001011×2^EXP
```

---

##### 2_Example 2

```
A-B = 100001001100101011100000 1 0 1×2^EXP
C   = 101001011010001110001000×2^(EXP-5) --> 
C   = 000001010010110100011100 0 1 0×2^EXP
```

2_1_If A-B-C is calculated after A-B is rounded:

```
Rounded A-B   = 100001001100101011100001×2^EXP
A-B-C         = 011111111001110111000100 1 1 0×2^EXP
A-B-C shifted 1 bit to left 
              = 111111110011101110001001 1 0 0×2^(EXP-1)
Rounded A-B-C = 11111111001110111000101×2^(EXP-1)
```

2_2_If A-B-C is calculated without A-B being rounded:

```
A-B-C         = 011111111001110111000100 0 1 1×2^EXP
A-B-C shifted 1 bit to left 
              = 111111110011101110001000 1 1 0×2^(EXP-1)
Rounded A-B-C = 111111110011101110001001×2^(EXP-1)
```

---

##### 3_Example 3

```
A-B = 10000001101000110101001 1 1 1×2^EXP

C   = 100010100101011010010000×2^(EXP-6) -->
C   = 000000100010100101011010 0 1 0×2^EXP
```

3_1_If A-B-C is calculated after A-B is rounded:

```
Rounded A-B = 10000001101000110101010×2^EXP
   A-B-C    = 01111101010100001001111 1 1 0×2^EXP
A-B-C shifted 1 bit to left 
            = 11111010101000010011111 1 0 0×2^(EXP-1)
Rounded A-B-C=11111010101000010100000×2^(EXP-1)
```

3_2_If A-B-C is calculated without A-B being rounded:

```
A-B-C       = 01111101010100001001111 1 0 1×2^EXP
A-B-C shifted 1 bit to left
            = 11111010101000010011111 0 1 0×2^(EXP-1)
Rounded A-B-C=11111010101000010011111×2^(EXP-1)
```

---

##### 4_Example 4

```
A-B = 101100101000111000110101 0 1 1×2^EXP

C = 100110010110011101100000×2^(EXP-7) --> 
C = 000000010011001011001110 1 1 0×2^EXP
```

4_1_If A-B-C is calculated after A-B is rounded:

```
Rounded A-B = 101100101000111000110110×2^EXP
A-B-C       = 101100010101101101100111 0 1 0×2^EXP
Rounded A-B-C=101100010101101101100111×2^EXP
```

4_2_If A-B-C is calculated without A-B being rounded:

```
A-B-C         = 101100010101101101100111 1 0 1×2^EXP
Rounded A-B-C = 101100010101101101101000×2^EXP
```

---

##### 5_Example 5

```
A-B = 100000111011001111001010 0 1 1×2^EXP

C = 110001011010010110010110×2^(EXP-3) --> 
C = 000110001011010010110010 1 1 0×2^EXP
```

5_1_If A-B-C is calculated after A-B is rounded:

```
Rounded A-B = 100000111011001111001010×2^EXP
A-B-C       = 011010101111111100010111 0 1 0×2^EXP
A-B-C shifted 1 bit to left
            = 110101011111111000101110 1 0 0×2^(EXP-1)
Rounded A-B-C=110101011111111000101110×2^(EXP-1)
```

5_2_If A-B-C is calculated without A-B being rounded:

```
A-B-C       = 011010101111111100010111 1 0 1×2^EXP
A-B-C shifted 1 bit to left 
            = 110101011111111000101111 0 1 0×2^(EXP-1)
Rounded A-B-C=110101011111111000101111×2^(EXP-1)
```

---

##### 6_Example 6

```
A-B = 100000000011000111001010 0 0 1×2^EXP
C = 110010001100110111000000×2^(EXP-8) -->
C = 000000001100100011001101 1 1 0×2^EXP
```

6_1_If A-B-C is calculated after A-B is rounded:

```
Rounded A-B = 100000000011000111001010×2^EXP
A-B-C       = 011111110110100011111100 0 1 0×2^EXP
A-B-C shifted 1 bit to left
            = 111111101101000111111000 1 0 0×2^(EXP-1)
Rounded A-B-C=111111101101000111111000×2^(EXP-1)
```

6_2_If A-B-C is calculated without A-B being rounded:

```
A-B-C       = 011111110110100011111100 0 1 1×2^EXP
A-B-C shifted 1 bit to left
            = 111111101101000111111000 1 1 0×2^(EXP-1)
Rounded A-B-C=111111101101000111111001×2^(EXP-1)
```

Comment: Unless you're doing it wrong things shouldn't get prematurely rounded... Perhaps an example or even a language you think is doing it?

Comment: what do you mean by prematurely? I mean when rounding to intended precision is needed

Comment: "rounding intermediate results" == rounding prematurely. You really should provide an example of what you think is going wrong...

Comment: I **think** I understand the question. Consider calculating the dot product of two length N vectors. According to the abstract of the referenced paper, it can be done with a single rounding operation. To the best of my knowledge, current hardware will do N rounding operations with fused multiply-add, 2*N without.

Comment: @john3136_well I don't think something is going WRONG! assume we're dealing with single-precision, when mantissa of result of addition of two ops has more than 24 bits it's then rounded to 24 bits am I wrong?

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan_yup :)

Comment: @PascalCuoq Not related at all

Comment: Semi-related: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [paper referenced in the question](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6567600), it is possible to calculate the dot product of a pair of length N vectors with a single rounding operation at the end, getting the closest representable result to the dot product.

In practice, current computers round intermediate results, which often results in an answer that is not the closest representable. At best, the rounding is to an extended format, which will tend to reduce, but not eliminate, intermediate result rounding error.

With a fused multiply-add the rounding is done N times, once for each multiply-add. Without a fused multiply-add it is done twice for each pair, once after the multiply and again after the add.

The BibTex information for the paper is:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{ yao:correctly,
AUTHOR = "Tao Yao and Deyuan Gao and Xiaoya Fan and Jari Nurmi",
TITLE = "Correctly rounded architectures for Floating-Point multi-operand addition and dot-product computation",
BOOKTITLE = "ASAP'13",
PAGES = {346-355},
YEAR = {2013}, 
}
```

Comment: To clarify it, I think it's about using intermediate results the mantissa of which have sticky bits and maybe guard and round bits, as operands of arithmetic operations without rounding them.

Comment: @Pooria I have not yet fully read the paper, but there is more to it than just using the guard and sticky bits. They are using a wide accumulator, and using it efficiently by relocating significant bits, retaining information about which group of bits are where.

Comment: Sure I meant to emphasize the fact that sticky or guard bits take part in arithmetic operations themselves unlike traditional system

Answer (score 2):

Some architectures will evaluate the intermediate results of an expression using an 80-bit "extended precision" floating-point type, even if those results will then be stored into a 64-bit or 32-bit type.  Unfortunately, today's programming languages often offer no control over that beyond allowing the choice of whether to "allow" or "forbid" it [they offer no way to request such behavior in places where it would be helpful].  It would in general be prohibitively expensive for languages to try to perform floating-point math with anything beyond an 80-bit extended-precision type.

Comment: C99 with FLT_EVAL_METHOD=0 lets you control the intermediate computations that should be in extended precision by using the type `long double`. GCC on Linux and Mac OS X offer 80-bit `long double`.

Comment: Is `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` something that compilers are required to let programmers set, or is it simply a way that compilers can promise the compiled code what semantics they're going to use?  I know that some compilers offer command-line options, but I don't think there's any standard for that.

Comment: `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is set by the compiler and cannot be set directly by the programmer. As you say, some compilers have command-line options (e.g. `-msse2 -mfppath=sse` for GCC) that change both the emitted instructions and, for quality compilers—ahem Clang ahem—the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: That's what I thought.  From what I can tell, it exists to allow code to select an algorithm or refuse to compile based upon what's available, but doesn't let a programmer control anything except by saying "Certain floating-point semantics must be set for this code to compile".  I am really annoyed at Microsoft for its failure to support 80-bit extended types, since there are many algorithms which, to achieve double-precision accuracy, would require more than twice as many steps when using double precision as when using extended; even if extended types...

Comment: ...took 16 bytes of storage each and were only half as fast as `double`, they'd still be better than `double` for many purposes.  I guess Microsoft is in love with SSE, but if using double takes three times as many steps as would using extended, where's the gain?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use interval arithmetik to control and bound the possible errors introduced by computer arithmetic. After the computation you get an interval which is guaranteed to contain the "true result". 
There are some implementations available for this. On the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) page for interval arithmetic there is a section on implementations which lists some libraries. In the late 1980ies I used Pacal-SC mentioned there while working as a programming tutor at Karlsruhe University :-)